# Question about a step in the proof of the min-max principle

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I honestly do not think this is a hard question, maybe it is even obvious but I tried MSE and had no success so far, so I am reproducing the question [Question about the proof of the min-max principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4769502/question-about-the-proof-of-the-min-max-principle) here.

Let $A$ be a densely defined self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$ which is bounded from below. The min-max principle states that:
$$\mu_{n}(A) := \inf_{\substack{M \subset D(A) \\ \text{dim}M = n}}\sup_{\substack{\psi \in M \\ \|\psi\| = 1}}\langle \psi, A\psi\rangle$$
is an increasing sequence $\mu_{n}(A) \to \mu_{\infty}(A) := \inf \sigma_{\text{ess}}(A)$. Moreover, if $\mu_{n}(A) < \mu_{\infty}(A)$ then $\mu_{n}(A)$ is the $n$-th lowest eigenvalue of $A$.

I am trying to understand the proof of the second part of this result. I already proved that $\mu_{1}(A)$ is the lowest eigenvalue of $A$ if $\mu_{1}(A) < \mu_{\infty}(A)$. Suppose then $\mu_{2}(A) < \mu_{\infty}(A)$. Since $\mu_{1}(A)$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, we can choose an associated eigenvector  $\varphi$. Of course we can decompose $\mathscr{H} = \text{span}\{\varphi\}\oplus W$, where $W = \{\varphi\}^{\perp}$. Let $A_{W}$ be the restriction of $A$ to $W$. Here is my question: the proof states that:
$$\mu_{2}(A) = \inf_{\substack{\psi \in W \\ \|\psi\| =1 }}\langle \psi, A_{W}\psi\rangle \equiv \mu_{1}(A_{W}).$$
Why is this true?

Comment: Where is the proof that you are studying?

Comment: @IosifPinelis I actually am using more than one reference, but my main reference is theorem 4.8 from these lecture notes : https://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~lampart/FA2_WS19_Lampart_week14.pdf

Comment: In the above link, the author proves the result by induction on $n$. So, in my case, once I have proven that $\mu_{1}(A) < \mu_{\infty}(A)$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $A$, I can assume the result follows from some $n > 1$ and prove it for $n+1$. I choose $n=2$ instead in my post because I was trying to understand the reasoning in this easier case, since the most general was even more difficult for me to understand.

Comment: The first equality follows because the optimal $M$ the definition of $\mu_2$ can be taken as a subspace containing $\varphi$. (Use the spectral theorem to see this.) The second equality follows because a minimizing $\psi$ gives us a minimizing subspace $M=L(\psi)$ in the original definition of $\mu_1$.

Comment: I think question about proofs of textbook results are usually better suited for (and will likely be better received at) https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ChristianRemling thanks for your comments. I have indeed posted the question on MSE first, but I got no answers so far. The question is even bountied there.

Comment: @MathMath: Thanks for clarifying. So I'll take back the part of my comment about the question being better received at MSE...